# Python kernel and jupyter extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode with the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.jupyter). For the Python extension, I have several interpreters available, installed by anaconda directly or different virtual environments I have created using conda. Thus, with the Python extension I can run code using different Python versions and packages. However, only one kernel is available for running the jupyter notebooks within vscode:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher
```

The `"jupyter mode"` in vscode does not recognize packages I have installed in my virtual environments. Is there a way to start the Python kernel for `"jupyter mode"` from one of my virtual environments? Or is there another way to solve this problem so that I can use a specific virtual environment in `"jupyter mode"` within **vscode**?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install the `ipykernel` for the different conda environments following instructions such as [these](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments). These kernels are then automatically identified by **vscode**.